# Check ModelState in Generic class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to Validate my model class in generic class, because I don't want to check every time in each method while input. Here is I have made a generic class but `ModelState.IsValid` not working.

```
public class Validator<T> where T : class
{
    public ApiResponse ValidateInput(T t)
    {
        try
        {
            if (t != null)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return JsonResponse.GetResponse(ResponseCode.Failure, ModelState.Values.FirstOrDefault().Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return JsonResponse.GetResponse(ResponseCode.Failure, ErrorMessage.InvalidRequest);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.CreateLog(ex);
            return JsonResponse.GetResponse(ResponseCode.Exception, ErrorMessage.Oops);
        }
    }
}
```

`ApiResponse` is my custom class that I've made for a specific type of response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `ModelState` is a `Controller` property. So you should implement your functionality in `BaseController` and then inherit. Does your code even compile?

Comment: Not it's not compiling, there is nothing after ModelState. IsValid I have put myself

Comment: @AliShahbaz if you describe all the detais of how desired solution should work in question it will help us to sugges you solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the `ModelState` is not working, While using `ModelState.IsValid` method if your model state is not valid, it will throw an error or do whatever you decided to do.

Yours is returning null, thus going for the else clause rather then the inner if for the `ModelState` check.

As for why I cannot possibly know since you did not share further code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is main portion for my problem, if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return JsonResponse.GetResponse(ResponseCode.Failure, ModelState.Values.FirstOrDefault().Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                }

Comment: No, the problem is that his code does not compile because `ModelState` is a `Controller` property.